# updating a php function

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any way to call a code snippet after every mysqli_query function is executed?
There is before and after insert triggers in MySQL. I am looking for something similar in PHP.

In the following example, I need to log all the warnings after every query automatically (i.e. without changing the current code)

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    print 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  if (!mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO dp4 (customer_id, first_name, last_name) ' .
                          'VALUES (NULL,"Chris","abc") ')) {
    print 'Failed to insert data: ' . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
  }
  if (($warnings = mysqli_warning_count($con)) > 0) {
    if ($rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW WARNINGS")) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
        printf("%s (%d): %s\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
        mysqli_free_result($rs);
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In other words, the code after **if (($warnings** should somehow run on it's own and log the warnings preferably to a text file.

Comment: Create a database class and encapsulate the query function.

Answer (score 5):

Not without changing the code. You should create your own querying function that performs the query, logs what it needs, returns the result and use that instead of mysqli_query().